# How to correctly read file to EOF

Tags: php, eof

I have a function that reads comments in a text file. Comment can last to end of line, if there is no end of line it lasts to end of file. My problem is I can't find out how to test it whether the end of file was reached. At first I had this:

```
while($char != "\n" && $char != false){
    $char = fgetc($inputFile);
}
```

If there was `0` in a comment it ended the loop which I didn't want to. Then I tried this:

```
while($char != "\n" && !feof($inputFile)){ 
    $char = fgetc($inputFile);
}
```

This broke up the whole program. I tried to google something but `feof` and `!= false` is all I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`!==`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to check for `FALSE`:

```
while($char != "\n" && $char !== FALSE){
    $char = fgetc($inputFile);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried `!==` too, but my program starts cycling after it.I have no idea why, because with `!=` it worked fine, it crashed only when it came to `0` character.

Comment: I just found out that mistake was somewhere else in the script, `!==` works fine now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Instead you can read your file until it reach end of line!

You can try [feof](http://php.net/manual/en/function.feof.php) function to check the end of file.

```
//Output a line of the file until the end is reached
while(!feof($file) {
    echo fgets($file) . "<br />";
}
fclose($file);
```

For fgets function if you do not specify the length then it will keep reading from the stream until it reaches the end of the line.